# Microsoft Word 2019: Permanently separating numbered lists

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a long document. I am adding numbered lists with many indentations like

1. a)
2. a) b) i)

where each new numbering system is marked by a new level of indentation, e.g. the numbers one tab to the right, the letters 2 tabs, the i, ii, iii system 3 tabs

When I now am done with that long list with many indentations I start a new section in the same document. When I make a new list it is automatically connected to the old one. That is, if I change the formatting on that list, by e.g. saying the indented numbers should be further to the right in my second list, they also move in the first list.

I want them to be completely separate. How can I, by default, separate these lists? I want the numbering not to continue, neither do I want the spacing / formatting to be connected. I do not even know why Word considers these lists to be linked when they're not even close to each other.

Comment: Please post a small document that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You click in the numbered list (1st level), then click on the arrow at *Start* > *Paragraph* > *Multi-level list*, and then define a *"new multi-level list"* below, paying attention to the following (especially if not only the style sheets, but also text already exists):

1. Apply changes for **complete** list
2. **Connect to the respective format template**, for example like this: Level 1>"List 1", Level 2>"List 2", etc.
3. Make sure that the checkmark next to **"Start list at ..."** is set and that the next higher level is set as the decisive factor (otherwise the numbering will always continue and does not start again).

See screenshots:

[image: Microsoft 2019: Permanently seperating numbered lists]
[image: Microsoft 2019: Permanently seperating numbered lists]
[image: Microsoft 2019: Permanently seperating numbered lists]